# Passing data between a ViewController to another ViewController with navigation controller Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, pass-data

I hope you'll be great, the point is I wanna pass data between `SeondViewController` to `HomeViewController` and navigation controller exist between them, but unfortunately, I can't. I try present call function it's work but the simulator stuck in `SecondView`, and here is my views photo:

[image: estoryboard]

My `secondViewController` button code to pass data to `homeViewcontroller` is:

```
   @IBAction func nextStep(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let thirdVC = HomeViewController()
    thirdVC.cid = cityId
      // present(thirdVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Also, my `homeViewController` code that I point to it , is here:

```
    class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

     var txt : String = "  "
     var cid : String = "  "
    
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
         print("\n iiiiiiiiiid is \(cid) ")
    }
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Are you using segues, to navigate from 1 view controller to another?

Comment: no , but I used prepare for segue I my button body but doesn't work, perhaps I didnt know where I should use that function and call

Comment: Ok use segue and add code given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67298027/10842413

Comment: You need to know the purpose of viewDidLoad, which won't read those two values.

Comment: I want to pass cityId data from SecondViewController to HomeViewController from button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using segue, then add "segue_identifier" in storyboard and the in secondviewcontroller add:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
             if segue.identifier == "segue_ identifier" {
                let mainTab = segue.destination as! tabBarController
                let nav = mainTab.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController
                let vc = nav.viewControllers.first as! HomeViewController
                vc.cid = cityId
            }
        }
```

Because your segue destination is UINavigationController, you need to send data to view controller like this

Comment: No, just add this below viewdidload

Comment: thanks for your answer but I used this in my IBAction button and said that override should delete

Comment: Share your Button action, do not add this code in IBAction

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x7fff898e3510) to 'UINavigationController' (0x7fff898e3a10). when i my app run app crash on Xcode and show this error , I test your answer and got this error in debug console area,

Comment: You need to implement performSegue to use prepare, and its possible to pass values with sender

Comment: yes i used that in my button but again I have last error

Comment: @Alikazemi, answer updated. You are getting this crash because there is UITabBarcontroller and UINavigation controller between 2 controllers

Comment: @iOSDeveloper yeah great answer thank you a lot brother for your help , now I could pass cityID again thanks and I really hope that every problem that stuck in, you get true answer speedly.